# running tsc command does nothing, ignores tsconfig file?

Tags: typescript

I have added typescript to my project and have created a `tsconfig.json`.
I wasn't planning on changing all the .js files to .ts files yet, so I put **`allowJS` to `true`** in the tsconfig.

But When I run `tsc` it does nothing. `tsc -p .` also does nothing.
`tsc --version` is 3.8.3. 
In the end I decided to run it on a single file:

```
tsc src/index.js
error TS6504: File 'src/index.js' is a JavaScript file. Did you mean to enable the 'allowJs' option?
```

So it looks like it's not seeing the tsconfig file at all? What am I doing wrong? I'm on windows.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes `tsc` ignores your `tsconfig.json` because you have passed it a file to process.

Typescript docs:

> When input files are specified on the command line, tsconfig.json files are ignored.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html

Use the `"include"` or `"files"` keys in your `tsconfig.json`.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "allowJs": true,
        "outDir": "dist"

    },
    "files": [
        "src/index.js"
    ]
}
```

Now run `tsc` and a the compiler will create a new directory `dist` with your `index.js` file.

Comment: I didn't know cmd line files cause tsconfig to be ignored! Thanks for that. Though, this didn't work for me. I originally had `"include": [
    "./src/**/*"
  ],` and it didn't work. Changed to "files" as shown above and it didn't work.

Comment: @yen can you share your tsconfig.json?

Comment: updated with tsconfig. Removed the part where i tried to run on the command line as you've explained why that didn't work. Now I mainly want it to work as per the tsconfig...

Comment: OMG... it's because I had "noEmit" isn't it? FACEPALM. That was from when i didn't want it to be a full typescript project yet... Pasting it makes it so obvious now...